Is there software with yq-like functionality that is based on pantoniou/libfyaml?
The yq tool is great, but it does not preserve whitespace and changes formatting of files outside of the intended change.
The libfyaml library seems to preserve formatting, but I haven't yet found a tool that delete and transform yaml nodes like yq that is based on that library. The fy-filter tool seems to only allow filtering for specific nodes as far as I can tell.
Does anyone have a recommendation for software with the power of yq that preserves formatting?
